# Switch condition evaluates to a constant in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I have this code

```
import UIKit

enum menuSituation{
    case menuIsOpened
    case menuIsClosed

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var currentSituation = menuSituation.menuIsClosed

        switch(currentSituation){ //Here is the warning
        case .menuIsOpened:
            println("Menu is opened")
            break
        case .menuIsClosed:
             println("Menu is closed")
            break

        }    
    }
```

In the line where I start to define switch statement, it gives me the warning :

> Switch condition evaluates to a constant

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, it basically means that the switch will always evaluate to `menuIsClosed`. You probably meant something like this:

```
var currentSituation = aSituation // That would be a menuSituation (known at runtime)

// Also note that 'break' is not needed in (non-empty) match cases
switch currentSituation {
    case .menuIsOpened:
        print("Menu is opened")
    case .menuIsClosed:
        print("Menu is closed")
}
```

Comment: I defined a function to return me a menuSituation type and then assigned it to currentSituation, so viewDidLoad became not aware of what the actual situation of the currentSituation variable is.And the warning is gone.Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, the solution was to make the **declaration globally**:

```
import UIKit

enum menuSituation{
    case menuIsOpened
    case menuIsClosed

}

private var currentSituation: menuSituation = .menuIsClosed // globally declaration

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        switch currentSituation { 
        case .menuIsOpened:
            println("Menu is opened")
            break
        case .menuIsClosed:
             println("Menu is closed")
            break

        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: The complete example makes it understand quick. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very often it helps to put a constant value into brackets. The compiler still knows it is a known value, but assumes for warnings etc. that it isn't. So just

```
var currentSituation = (menuSituation.menuIsClosed)
```

I assume this is during development, and you will add other cases, otherwise the warning is of course fully justified and you can much simplify the code.

Answer (score -2):

Probably you can try in this way

```
 enum CompassPoint : String {
 case North
 case South
 case East
 case West
 }
   let directionToHead = "West"

    switch directionToHead {
    case "North":
        print("Lots of planets have a north")
    case "South":
        print("Watch out for penguins")
    case "East":
        print("Where the sun rises")
    case "West":
        print("Where the skies are blue")
    default :
        print("No direction is found")
    }
```